# UMBRACO 10 HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: asp.net-core, umbraco

I am trying to deploy my Website with umbraco 10, I always get the following error:

**HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start**

The website works correctly locally, however when deploying the app I get the same error...

**Details**:

- DB SQL Server
- Azure WebApp .Net6

What i have tried

1. I have followed the instructions: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Fundamentals/Setup/Server-Setup/azure-web-apps
2. I have created a project from scratch, thinking that the problem was some package, but still the same error.

This is how my umbraco 10 application looks once deployed from VS to an appservice (Azure)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is check the logs on the the environment where you have deployed the code. That should give you a better idea what is actually going wrong as the error you are getting is very generic and not that helpful.

I have seen issues where the `media` folder is missing and that is something to check.

When I have issues in Azure, I also look at the files via the Azure Portal and check the connection string and any other configurations files to ensure they look correct. It could be the deployment has screwed up some values.

Have a look at this post which may provide some further details - https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/108288-getting-http-error-50030-after-successful-publishing-to-azure

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Unfortunately, none of those steps worked for me.

I have evaluated the resource more closely and I notice that when deploying an application with umbraco 10(.net6), not all the elements are deployed in the appserive, and they are not uploaded with the source folder either, but individually.

I have carried out multiple tests with applications outside of Umbraco in this version (.net6) and they have been deployed without any problem. I have edited the post placing the image of what my umbraco 10 application looks like once deployed from VS to an appservice (Azure)